# How do I mount my laptop's hard-disk in a remote server (reverse sshfs)?

Tags: server, 18.04, mount, ssh, sshfs

I was wondering if there is a way to mount a local directory/hard-disk in another server (like sshfs 
 but vice versa)

I know it should be possible to use sshfs from the other machine while my own system is accessible by ssh but am wondering if there is another way.
Thanks.

The main problem is the limited storage space of the remote machine.

Comment: Instead of doing vice versa like you already written, have you think about simple possibilities of doing `scp` from your local with all options that suits you?

Comment: @TadejP the problem is mainly the limited storage space of the remote machine.